# How to use $_POST to send data to a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

Hey guys, I wanted to know how to send data to a wordpress page using $_POST ?
and that page has a template named data_page.php
What should be the action value in the form ? data_page.php or myweb.com/data-page/ ?

and thank you :D

Comment: what's the permalink of that page?

Comment: Avoid phrases like "Hey guys" and "thank you" in your question.  Those things are implied and take away from the content of the question.

Comment: @mella I actually find questions with that more appealing, and I am more likely to answer those.

Comment: @Emil: As SO presents itself as a community-edited library of questions, they should be questions, not personalized requests.  At least in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mod_rewrite, (http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks like this explains), and http://myweb.com/data-page/ is mapped to a function, you can simply write
    `<form action="http://myweb.com/data-page/" method="POST"></form>`